# Как в OrientDB контролировать уникальность полей?

Tags: sql, nosql, база-данных

Я использую document model. Как создавать поле, которое будет уникальным? Документы создаю вот так:

```
ODocument doc = new ODocument("GitStorage");
    doc.field("id", id);
    doc.field("date", new java.util.Date());
    doc.field("h", h);
    doc.field("m", m);
    doc.field("l", l);
```